# Cloudflare Flexible SSL and secure email forms

Tags: forms, security, ssl, cloudflare

If I was needing a secure contact form that uses SSL to encrypt/secure a contact email form would I need an actual SSL certificate or would CloudFlare's Flexible SSL be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Cloudflare, Flexible SSL only provides SSL between the visitor and CloudFlare. Therefore visitor sees HTTPS on your site, but there will be no SSL between CloudFlare and your web server. However your visitors will still see the site as being HTTPS enabled. But This doesn't mean that you will get secure connection all the way from client to server. If you really need security, go with cloudflare's Full SSL or Full SSL (Strict). In that case You'll need to have a valid SSL certificate installed on your web server.

References : [SSL at CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-Off-Flexible-SSL-Full-SSL-Full-SSL-Strict-mean-)